# Windows not working properly

Tags: windows-7, bootloader

Hey guys I booted into my windows 7 after a month and there is some error. Not able to do any work on it properly. I dont have any problem in reinstalling windows but the issue is that it will overtake grub and I wont be able to boot into ubuntu. So let me know exact measures that I can take at the moment.

Will recovering my windows too overtake grup bootloader.

Note Error in windows : Error- file or directory C:\$Mft is corrupt and unreadable. Run chkdsk utility. wlmail.exe corrupt file.

Thanks

Comment: Regarding: `Note Error in windows : Error- file or directory C:\$Mft is corrupt and unreadable. Run chkdsk utility. wlmail.exe corrupt file.` No one on AU is going to anwser that since this is purely related to Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to re-install your Windows. Just do as Windows say and run [chkdsk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHKDSK)

Comment: Yeah I knew that but actually it was not opening..and I was facing some problem but issue solved now...thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

No problem with reinstalling windows 7 . Go ahead.. After installing windows 7 , First you insert the ubuntu cd and update the grub bootloader. The steps are,

1). Boot the ubuntu using live cd .

2). Open the terminal

3). type the command **sudo udate-grub.**

4). reboot

Comment: Error- file or directory C:\$Mft is corrupt and unreadable. Run chkdsk utility. wlmail.exe corrupt file.